# Why am I getting a multiple statements found while compiling a single statement error? (Python)

Tags: python

I keep getting an error in this rudimentary calculator program in Python version 3.3.1. I cannot find the problem myself, can someone help me? Thank you very much in advance!

```
    x=(input("Which operation would you like to perform?"))
        if x=='Addition':
        y=int(input("Enter the first number?"))
        z=int(input("Enter the second number?"))
        a=y+z
        print(a)
    elif x=='Subtraction':
        y=int(input("Enter the first number?"))
        z=int(input("Enter the second number?"))
        a=y-z
        print(a)
    elif x=='Multiplication':
        y=int(input("Enter the first number?"))
        z=int(input("Enter the second number?"))
        a=y*z
        print(a)
elif x=='Division':
        y=int(input("Enter the first number?"))
        z=int(input("Enter the second number?"))
        a=y/z
        print(a)
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: I think you just have an indentation problem. Or is it just from the copy-paste? And why the extra parenthesis on the first input() call? Try re-tabulating.

Comment: That's just from the copy paste sorry

Comment: The error only says "SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement"
It's on the first line, "x=(input("Which operation would you like to perform?"))"

Comment: And why the extra parenthesis on the first input() call?

Comment: You're right I don't need the extra parenthesis but I still get the error

Comment: Actually, the paste might have just revealed the problem !!

Comment: @user2399322: Post all of your code. It's probably on the line before it.

Comment: @Blender This is all of my code, do I need to have anything before this?

Comment: @user2399322: How are you running this code? Are you copy/pasting it into something?

Comment: For what it is worth, I copied and pasted the code from the original post and ran it in Python version 3.2.1 and it worked just fine; could not reproduce the error.

Comment: I'll try downloading that version if I can't fix the error, thank you!

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @Blender I'm using the IDLE python gui

Comment: @user2399322: But how are you running it? Are you pasting it into the shell? Are you using the editor and then running it through that?

Comment: @Blender I'm pasting it into the shell and pressing enter on the last line

Comment: @user2399322: That's probably why. Run it normally though the editor.

Comment: @Blender I'm very inexperienced with the gui, How would I run it through the editor?

Comment: Press `F5`. That should do it. EDIT - Do File->New Window. Paste the code there, save and then F5.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you so much! I didn't even realize that the shell was just a place to test code instead of running it!

Answer (score 0):

Your tabs are messed up I think, try something like this :

```
x=input("Which operation would you like to perform?")
if x=='Addition':
    y=int(input("Enter the first number?"))
    z=int(input("Enter the second number?"))
    a=y+z
    print(a)
elif x=='Subtraction':
    y=int(input("Enter the first number?"))
    z=int(input("Enter the second number?"))
    a=y-z
    print(a)
elif x=='Multiplication':
    y=int(input("Enter the first number?"))
    z=int(input("Enter the second number?"))
    a=y*z
    print(a)
elif x=='Division':
    y=int(input("Enter the first number?"))
    z=int(input("Enter the second number?"))
    a=y/z
    print(a)
```

Comment: @user2399322 I copy/pasted the code block from this answer verbatim, and it works for me.

Comment: @Aya are you using the idle python gui? And are you on version 3.3.1?

Comment: @user2399322 Check your `python -V` I believe you are accidentally using 2.X to run the code.

Comment: @Emil The version on top states " Python 3.3.1 (v3.3.1:d9893d13c628, Apr  6 2013, 20:30:21) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 "

Comment: @Emil I still get "SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement"

Answer (score -1):

`x= raw_input("Which operation would you like to perform?")` will solve ur problem

EDIT: In python 3 raw_input is renamed to input() to get the old behavior use `eval(input(....))`  reference http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins

Hope this helps

Comment: Using raw_input gives me a traceback 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
        x=raw_input("Which operation would you like to perform?")
   NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3.